# Question about storing magnetic parts (DC motors and speakers)

Tags: dc-motor, speakers, magnetics, magnet

I always have a problem with storing magnetic parts, namely DC motors and speakers, because I am afraid if I let them attach together their magnets could interact and weaken/damage each other.

So I try to put them a reasonable distance apart so they don't attach together but it's becoming a real hassle as their number increases.

I wanted to know if there's any problem with just sticking them all together (they'll literally stick together because they're magnetic) and putting them in a box.

Comment: Be careful of the "flying screwdriver into speaker cone" phenomena. That is, speakers tend to have other metal objects pierce the center of their cone, because the strongest magnetic flux is concentrated there.

Comment: @rdtsc Will do, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern magnets won't suffer from this problem and older magnets only suffer from this when the threat magnet is producing an opposing field to the victim magnet so, if you feel a degree of repulsion between threat and victim, then it's probably a good idea to segregate them especially if they are old magnet materials.

On the other hand, if you segregate the magnets with mild steel plates, you are unlikely to get a problem.

> *I wanted to know if there's any problem with just sticking them all
> together (they'll literally stick together because they're magnetic)
> and putting them in a box.*

If they stick together then you are not imposing opposite fields and there will be no demagnetization in this respect.

Comment: I feel like when they stick together, say for example 4 motors stuck together, there might still be some repelling forces. With magnets of the same shape you can just stack them together and all their N and S poles will be aligned. But with motors for example, the shape is irregular so there's no guarantee that N&S poles will completely align and even tho they're stuck there might be some repelling forces still. Won't that be a problem?

Comment: If in doubt, use mild steel separators @PouriaP

Comment: I suppose other kinds of metal don't work? I have some metal sheet but I don't know what's it's made of really. I also have some galvanized thin strips.

Comment: If it's magnetisable it'll be a good separator.